# How to combine multiple arrays and a string into one array?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following object:

```js
const test = {
  resources: {
    gatewayApi: {
      resourceUri: 'https://bla',
      resourceScope: 'D',
    },
    msGraphProfile: {
      resourceUri: 'https://foo',
      resourceScope: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    },
    msGraphMail: {
      resourceUri: 'https://bar',
      resourceScope: ['A'],
    },
    msGraphGroupMember: {
      resourceUri: 'https://bob',
    },
  },
}
```

The goal is to achieve a single array containing only the unique values defined in `resourceScope`:

```js
const result = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

To get to the desired result I took these steps:

```js
// first create a new array with key value pairs
const newArray = Object.entries(test.resources)

// return only those values that have the property `resourceScope`
const result = newArray.filter(([, val]) => {
  if ('resourceScope' in val) { return val.resourceScope }
})
```

At this point I'm a bit stuck. I would need to combine all returned arrays and a single string ('A') into one clean `array`. I've tried looking for examples but I couldn't really figure it out.

Thank you for your  help.

Comment: You can loop an objects values with a " for in" and you can find a key with "hasownproperty".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `flatMap`, `filter` and `Set` I could able to achieve this. Hope this will be helpful

```js
const test = {"resources":{"gatewayApi":{"resourceUri":"https://bla","resourceScope":"D"},"msGraphProfile":{"resourceUri":"https://foo","resourceScope":["A","B","C"]},"msGraphMail":{"resourceUri":"https://bar","resourceScope":["A"]},"msGraphGroupMember":{"resourceUri":"https://bob"}}}

const resultSet = new Set(Object.values(test.resources).flatMap(resource => resource.resourceScope).filter(resourceScope => resourceScope))

const resultArray = Array.from(resultSet)
console.log(resultArray)
```

Comment: This looks really clean! Thank you, I like it.

Comment: Thank you and I'm glad that it helped. :-)

Comment: I'm new to javaScript but I wonder why it's not possible to simply to this `const resultArray = Object.values(test.resources).flatMap((r) => r.resourceScope).filter((r)=> r)`

Comment: If we don't use `Set`, then the data might get repeated which is not intended. Otherwise again we'll have to filter from the resultant array. In order to avoid that used `Set` which will hold unique values.

Comment: I [see now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), when we use `new Set()` it creates a `Set` object and not an object of type `array`. I was a bit confused there I think. Thanks again for the great help!

Comment: No Problem. Pleasure is mine :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213905/discussion-between-nithish-gandesiri-and-darklite1).

Answer (score 2):

You could use `reduce` method with `Set` as accumulator value to get unique values and then create an array from that set.

```js
const test = {"resources":{"gatewayApi":{"resourceUri":"https://bla","resourceScope":"D"},"msGraphProfile":{"resourceUri":"https://foo","resourceScope":["A","B","C"]},"msGraphMail":{"resourceUri":"https://bar","resourceScope":["A"]},"msGraphGroupMember":{"resourceUri":"https://bob"}}}

const uniq = Object
  .values(test.resources)
  .reduce((r, e) => {
    [].concat(e.resourceScope)
      .forEach(e => {
        if (e) r.add(e)
      })

    return r;
  }, new Set)


const result = Array.from(uniq)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct for you ?

```
const test = {
  resources: {
    gatewayApi: {
      resourceUri: 'https://bla',
      resourceScope: 'D',
    },
    msGraphProfile: {
      resourceUri: 'https://foo',
      resourceScope: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    },
    msGraphMail: {
      resourceUri: 'https://bar',
      resourceScope: ['A'],
    },
    msGraphGroupMember: {
      resourceUri: 'https://bob',
    },
  },
}
let tab = []
for(let [key,value] of Object.entries(test.resources)){
  for(let v in value.resourceScope){
    if(!tab.includes(value.resourceScope[v])){
      tab.push(value.resourceScope[v])
    }
  }
  console.log(tab);
}
```